# swift nsobject class how to return value

Tags: swift, class, nsobject

i am new in swift how to create common class and return string Here is my code where i do mistake Please help me. This is my nsobject common class

```
import UIKit

    class DayCount: NSObject {

        func doSomething(getDate:String)  -> String   {


            let start = "2015­06­01"

            let end = NSDate()

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy­MM­dd"

            var endDateSting:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(end)

            let startDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(start)!

            let endDate:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(endDateSting)!

            let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

            let unit:NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitDay

            let components = cal.components(unit, fromDate: startDate, toDate:

                endDate, options: nil)

            println(components)
            let date:String? = (self.timeAgoSinceDate(startDate, numericDates: Bool()))

            println(date)

            return date!


            }

        func timeAgoSinceDate(date:NSDate, numericDates:Bool) -> String {
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

            let unitFlags = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute |

                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay |

                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear

            NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear |

                NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond

            let now = NSDate()

            let earliest = now.earlierDate(date)

            let latest = (earliest == now) ? date : now

            let components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(unitFlags,

                fromDate: earliest, toDate: latest, options: nil)

            if (components.year >= 2) {

            } else if (components.year >= 1){

            } else if (components.month >= 2) {

            } else if (components.month >= 1){

            } else if (components.weekOfYear >= 2) {

            } else if (components.weekOfYear >= 1){

            } else if (components.day >= 2) {

            } else if (components.day >= 1){

            } else if (components.hour >= 2) {

            } else if (components.hour >= 1){

                return "\(components.year) years ago"

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 year ago"

                } else {

                    return "Last year"

                }

                return "\(components.month) months ago"

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 month ago"

                } else {

                    return "Last month"

                }

                return "\(components.weekOfYear) weeks ago"

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 week ago"

                } else {

                    return "Last week"

                }

                return "\(components.day) days ago"

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 day ago"

                } else {

                    return "Yesterday"

                }

                return "\(components.hour) hours ago"

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 hour ago"

                } else {

                    return "An hour ago"

                }

            } else if (components.minute >= 2) {

                return "\(components.minute) minutes ago"

            } else if (components.minute >= 1){

                if (numericDates){

                    return "1 minute ago"

                } else {

                    return "A minute ago"

                }

            } else if (components.second >= 3) {

                return "\(components.second) seconds ago"

            } else {

                return "Just now"

            }
            return ""
        }





    }
```

and my view controller i have get this string like this but its return always error

```
let getdate = (DayCount.doSomething("sdfsdfsd")) 
        println("date===== \(getdate)")
```

The error is "(string)-> string is not convertible to DayCount"
i have also Try this

```
let getdate:String = (DayCount.doSomething("sdfsdfsd"))
        println("date===== \(getdate)")
```

But it always return me error please help me where i do mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let getdate = (DayCount.doSomething("sdfsdfsd"))
```

won't work because it's not correct syntax. 
doSomething is a method, DayCount is a class. A method is invoked on an instance variable of a class.
eg

```
var aDayCounter : DayCount
```

is a way to define a variable of type Daycount. On that type you can then invoke the method

```
aDayCounter.doSomething("sdfsdfsd")
```

You can also define Class methods or Type methods as they're called in Swift. the Apple dev site explains this better than I can do:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Comment: I get this now. Variable 'aDayCounter' used before being initialized. please help

Comment: you can either make it an optional or add an init function to your class